# How do I pass a pointer to a structure without angering the compiler?

Tags: c++, reference, struct, mingw, structure

I'm attempting to compile a simple C++ program using MinGW 4.7.2, but am frustrated by a deluge of errors and warnings.

```
/*\ program.h \*/
typedef struct
{   int member0;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
} structure;

void function(&structure);
```

---

```
/*\ program.cpp \*/
#include "program.h"

int main(void)
{   structure *instance;
    function(instance);
}

void function(&structure)
{   // nothing
}
```

`function` takes the address of a `structure`. Pointer `instance` contains the address of a `structure` which is then passed to `function`.

Simple, but the compiler is not happy.

```
g++ program.cpp
In file included from program.cpp:1:0:
program.h:8:14: error: variable or field 'function' declared void
program.h:8:25: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
program.cpp: In function 'int main()':
program.cpp:5:19: error: 'function' was not declared in this scope
program.cpp: At global scope:
program.cpp:8:14: error: variable or field 'function' declared void
program.cpp:8:25: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

What is `variable or field 'function' declared void` trying to tell me? `function` is obviously `void`, but how is that bad? I've spent several hours searching for these answers, but without success.

How can I pass a pointer to a structure without making the compiler vomit?

Comment: You badly need a book which teaches the basics. Even one of those learn C or learn C++ in 2 minutes should help.

Comment: I've read _The C Programming Language_ along with many other documents and tutorials, though I've read nothing on C++. Which parts of my program exhibit bad practice?

Comment: There is no bad practice. It's just wrong stuff. Very basic syntax is wrong. Why don't start by copying programs from the book?

Comment: `typedef struct` is not idiomatic C++. It's C. Just use `struct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this (see my comments in the code... pretty much what the compiler is telling you):

```
/*\ program.h \*/
typedef struct
{   int member0;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
} structure;

void function(&structure);

/*\ program.cpp \*/
#include "program.h"

int main(void)
{   structure *instance; // this is not an instance. it is a pointer

    function(instance);
}

void function(&structure) // this is an invalid declaration
{   // nothing
}
```

Do this:

```
/*\ program.h \*/
struct structure
{   int member0;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

void function(structure& s); // parameter 's' is a reference to your structure

/*\ program.cpp \*/
#include "program.h"

int main(void)
{   structure instance; // this is an instance

    function(instance);
}

void function(structure& s) 
{   // nothing
}
```

You need to appreciate the differences between instances, pointers, and references...and also know the valid syntax of each whether you are declaring variables or function interfaces.

Alternatively, you could pass a pointer to your instance like this:

```
/*\ program.h \*/
struct structure
{   int member0;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

void function(structure* p);

/*\ program.cpp \*/
#include "program.h"

int main(void)
{   structure instance; // you still need an instance to point to

    function(&instance); // this passes the address of the instance into the function
}

void function(structure* p)
{   // nothing
}
```

Whether to use references or pointers depends on what you are trying to do.
You should also consider using const to make it clearer whether your function will modify the contents of the struct, and also assist the compiler with optimizing your code.

Finally, fix errors one at a time starting with the top one. Often, the second and subsequent errors change (or disappear) once the first one is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*\ program.cpp \*/
#include "program.h"
void function(structure*);

int main(void)
{   structure instance;
    function(&instance);
}

void function(structure*)
{   // nothing
}
```

Comment: did u change the function prototype in header file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want/need to use typedefs to declare structs in C++, and your function should accept a pointer to them - denoted `Structure*`...

```
/*\ program.h \*/
struct Structure
{   int member0;
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
};

void function(Structure*);
```

---

Your program just makes the same little change to pass/expect a pointer.  (`main(void)` is a C thing - just `main()` is enough for C++)

```
/*\ program.cpp \*/
#include "program.h"

int main()
{
    Structure* instance;
    function(instance);
}

void function(Structure*)
{   // nothing
}
```

Comment: @ZoomIn correct. Any attempts to deference `instance` in this case would be undefined.

Comment: greatwolf's right - you could write `int main() { Structure instance; function(&instance); }` to pass an actual instance instead of an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: Just a note as someone tried to edit the answer's example code (and several people rejected that edit before I'd ever seen it)... it may be that John wanted to add some code to give the pointer a valid value, so I wanted to illustrate code as similar to his original answer as possible... let him fill in the blanks.  If he wanted a stack-based instance then that's now documented in the comment above too.  Cheers